# PHP: output one line HTML-document without preg_replace

Tags: php, templates, view

I need to ouput HTML-document as single line string to save network traffic between server and client.
One of popular approaches is to use `preg_replace`, which have disadvantage of being slow:

```
$html = preg_replace('~>\s+<~', '><', $html);
```

Another approach is to turn on GZip on front-end, which is better solution. But that if I will use following approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><?php
?><html><?php
?><head><?php
  ?><title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title><?php
?></head><?php
?><body><?php
  ?><div><?php
    ?><h1><?php echo $page_title; ?></h1><?php
  ?></div><?php
?></body><?php
?></html>
```

Byte-code of compiled scripts are stored in APC. What disadvantages of this approach, except lesser readability?

Answer (score 0):

Gzip is a no-brainer, there is never a reason to not use it.

You could look at how much you gain by trimming whitespace in HTML, overall I don't think it's worth it useless you are at the scale of Google, Twitter or Facebook. The readability cost and/or CPU overhead is not worth it.

I wouldn't worry about compiled script size, just feed it more RAM if you really run into issues.